# 8-Queens algorithm example?

Tags: c#, algorithm, n-queens

Anybody knows good/concise algorithm examples for [8-queens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)? 
I did a Web search and did not find any good example.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Google has tons of hits for this. Whether they're good is another question, but I'm sure at least one of them is...

Comment: The basic algorithm to search for solutions is trivial. Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: Is there any reason this is only tagged with c#? Or is this homework that needs to be coded in c#?

Comment: "I did a Web search and did not find any good example." lol

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple Java implementation of the naive recursive algorithm; it should be instructive.

```
public class NQueens {
    final static int N = 4;
    static int[] position = new int[N];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        solve(0);
    }

    static boolean isSafe(int k, int p) {
//      for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
//          int other = position[k - i];
//          if (other == p || other == p - i || other == p + i) {
//              return false;
//          }
//      }
        return true;
    }
    static void solve(int k) {
        if (k == N) {
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(position));
        } else {
            for (char p = 0; p < N; p++) {
                if (isSafe(k, p)) {
                    position[k] = p;
                    solve(k+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `isSafe` contains commented lines right now; it's done on purpose. With these lines commented, the program becomes a recursive `N`-tuple generator, where each value is between `0` (inclusive) and `N` (exclusive). That is, the program as is generates the following output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 3]
:
:
[3, 3, 3, 0]
[3, 3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

This `N`-tuple generation is a concrete sub-problem of the NQueens problem. There are many questions already on stackoverflow on how to write an `N`-nested loops, when you don't know what `N` is. I feel that it's instructional to make a temporary stop at this problem and first understand its solution, with `isSafe` commented out to simply `return true;`, to first get a feel of what the recursion does.

Once you're comfortable that this recursive tuple generator works, simply uncomment those lines, and you will get a simple, naive, but working, NQueens solver. With `N=5` and `isSafe` lines uncommented, the program now generates the following output:

```
[0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
[0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
[1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 0, 3]
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 4, 1, 3, 0]
[3, 0, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 1, 4, 2, 0]
[4, 1, 3, 0, 2]
[4, 2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Each line is a solution to the 5-queens problem. The `i`-th element of the array denotes the row position of the `i`-th queen placed on the `i`-th column (all indices are 0-based). So, the first solution looks like this on the board:

```
[0,2,4,1,3]

 Q · · · ·
 · · · Q ·
 · Q · · ·
 · · · · Q
 · · Q · ·
```

I will leave it as an exercise to understand why `isSafe` works, and how to print the board layout, and how to implement faster but more complicated recursive algorithms.

Happy learning.

Answer (score 3):

The point of the 8-queens problem is often just to illustrate the power of search combined with pruning. You can pretty much do a brute force search of the search space, but eliminate any partial solution when it violates the constraints of the solution (i.e. one queen checks another).

Just using this pruning, 8-queens is easily solvable.

If you want more efficient solutions that would be useful for e.g. 100 or 1000 queens, that's a different story and you can look at the stuff in wikipedia. But for 8-queens, brute force and pruning are enough. (i.e. do depth first search of the search space, eliminating any intermediate node that includes a queen in check).

Answer (score 3):

to place queen on row r:

```
if r = 0 then you're done -- return ok
for each c [1 .. 8]:
  if (r,c) is safe:
    mark (r,c)
    if you can place queen on row r-1 then return ok
    unmark (r,c)  (if you're here, this c won't work)
return not ok     (if you're here, no c generated a solution)
```

(r,c) is safe if, for each row [r+1 .. 8]:

- (row,c) is not marked
- c - (row - r) < 1 or (row, c - (row - r)) is not marked
- c + (row - r) > 8 or (row, c + (row - r)) is not marked

Answer (score 2):

```
// Demonstration of the 8-Queens problem

// This handout shows interactively how the 8-Queens problem can be solved
// using recursion and backtracking (with exhaustive search with pruning).

// As far as this code goes, some improvements can definitely be made,
// especially with regard to the interface and the flexibility for the
// user.  However, it does an adequate job of showing the steps involved in
// solving the 8-Queens problem.

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JRQueens extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    public ChessSquare [][] squares;
    public boolean [] saferow;   // is the row empty?  true or false
    public boolean [] safeleftdiag; // is the left (from upper right to lower left)
    // diagonal unthreatened?  true or false
    public boolean [] saferightdiag; // is the right (from upper left to lower right)
    // diagonal unthreatened?  true or false

    private ShapePanel drawPanel; // panel for the board to be drawn -- see details
    // in class definition below
    private JLabel info;  // informative label
    private JButton runDemo; // button to allow interaction
    private Thread runThread; // thread to allow "motion"
    private int delay;   // delay between moves
    private PauseClass pauser; // class to allow execution to pause in between
    // solutions -- see details in definition below
    private boolean paused;  // is execution paused?  true or false
    private int sol, calls;

    public JRQueens(int delta)
    {
        super("Interactive 8 Queens Problem");
        delay = delta;
        drawPanel = new ShapePanel(450, 450);

        runDemo = new JButton("See Solutions");  // Set up button
        ButtonHandler bhandler = new ButtonHandler();
        runDemo.addActionListener(bhandler);

        info = new JLabel("The 8 Queens Problem", (int) CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        Container c = getContentPane();   // Set up layout
        c.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(info, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(runDemo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        squares = new ChessSquare[8][8]; // initialize variables
        saferow = new boolean[8];
        safeleftdiag = new boolean[15];
        saferightdiag = new boolean[15];
        int size = 50;
        int offset = 25;
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        {
            saferow[row] = true;  // all rows are safe
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
            {
                squares[row][col] = new ChessSquare(offset + col*size, 
                offset + row*size, 
                size, size);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {                               // initialize all diagonals to safe
            safeleftdiag[i] = true;
            saferightdiag[i] = true;
        }
        sol = 0;
        calls = 0;

        runThread = null;

        setSize(475, 525);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // Is the current location safe?  We check the row and both diagonals.
    // The column does not have to be checked since our algorithm proceeds in
    // a column by column manner.
    public boolean safe(int row, int col)
    {
        return (saferow[row] && safeleftdiag[row+col] &&
        saferightdiag[row-col+7]);
    }

    // This recursive method does most of the work to solve the problem.  Note
    // that it is called for each column tried in the board, but, due to
    // backtracking, will overall be called many many times.  Each call is from
    // the point of view of the current column, col.
    public void trycol(int col)
    {
        calls++; // increment number of calls made
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)    // try all rows if necessary
        {
            // This test is what does the "pruning" of the execution tree --
            // if the location is not safe we do not bother to make a recursive
            // call from that position, saving overall many thousands of calls.
            // See notes from class for details.
            if (safe(row, col))
            {
                // if the current position is free from a threat, put a queen
                // there and mark the row and diags as unsafe
                saferow[row] = false;
                safeleftdiag[row+col] = false;
                saferightdiag[row-col+7] = false;
                (squares[row][col]).occupy();
                repaint();

                if (col == 7)      // queen safely on every column, announce
                {                  // solution and pause execution
                    sol++;
                    info.setText("Solution " + sol + " Found After " + calls + " Calls");
                    runDemo.setText("Click to Continue");
                    runDemo.setEnabled(true);
                    pauser.pause();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Still more columns left to fill, so delay a bit and then
                    // try the next column recursively
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thread error B");
                    }

                    trycol(col+1);  // try to put a queen onto the next column
                }

                saferow[row] = true;               // remove the queen from
                safeleftdiag[row+col] = true;      // the current row and
                saferightdiag[row-col+7] = true;   // unset the threats. The
                (squares[row][col]).remove();      // loop will then try the
                // next row down
            } 
        }
    // Once all rows have been tried, the method finishes, and execution
    // backtracks to the previous call.
    }

    // This method executes implicitly when the Thread is started.  Note that
    // its main activity is the call trycol(0), which starts the recursive
    // algorithm on its way.
    public void run()
    {
        paused = false;
        pauser = new PauseClass();
        trycol(0);
        repaint();
        info.setText("Program Completed: " + sol + " Solutions, "
        + calls + " Calls, "
        + (8*calls) + " iterations ");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // Use the delay value entered by the user, or use 100 if no
        // value is entered.
        int delay;
        if (args != null && args.length >= 1)
        delay = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        else
        delay = 100;
        JRQueens win = new JRQueens(delay);

        win.addWindowListener(
            new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                { System.exit(0); }
            }
        );
    }

    // This class is used to enable the execution to pause between
    // solutions.  The Java details of this class have to do with monitors
    // and synchronized Threads and are beyond the scope of the CS 1501
    // course.  However, if you are interested in learning more about these
    // Java features, feel free to look them up in the Java API.
    private class PauseClass
    {
        public synchronized void pause()
        {
            paused = true;
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Pause Problem");
            }
        }

        public synchronized void unpause()
        {
            paused = false;
            notify();
        }
    }

    // Class to handle button.  For more on the Java details, see
    // the API online.
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == runDemo)
            {
                if (!paused)
                {
                    runDemo.setEnabled(false);
                    info.setText("Searching for Solutions");
                    runThread = new Thread(JRQueens.this);
                    runThread.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    runDemo.setEnabled(false);
                    info.setText("Searching for Solutions");
                    pauser.unpause();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    // Inner class to represent a square on the board.  This class extends
    // Rectangle2D.Double, which can be drawn graphically by the draw() method
    // of the Graphics2D class.  The main additions I have made in the subclass
    // are the occupied variable and the drawing of the Q if the space is
    // occupied.
    private class ChessSquare extends Rectangle2D.Double
    {
        private boolean occupied;

        public ChessSquare(double x1, double y1, double wid, double hei)
        {
            super(x1, y1, wid, hei);
            occupied = false;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
        {
            g2d.draw(this);
            int x = (int) this.getX();
            int y = (int) this.getY();
            int sz = (int) this.getWidth();

            if (occupied)
            {
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 36));
                g2d.drawString("Q", x+10, y+sz-10);
            }
        }

        public void occupy()
        {
            occupied = true;
        }

        public void remove()
        {
            occupied = false;
        }

        public boolean isOccupied()
        {
            return occupied;
        }
    }

    // Class that allows the board to be rendered in a nice way.
    // See that Java API or a good book on Java graphics for more
    // details about this class.
    private class ShapePanel extends JPanel
    {
        private int prefwid, prefht;

        public ShapePanel (int pwid, int pht)
        {
            prefwid = pwid;
            prefht = pht;
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return new Dimension(prefwid, prefht);
        }

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    (squares[i][j]).draw(g2d);
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle):

> This heuristic solves n queens for any n n ≥ 4 or n = 1:
>
> 1. Divide n by 12. Remember the
>    remainder (n is 8 for the eight
>    queens puzzle).
> 2. Write a list of the
>    even numbers from 2 to n in order.
> 3. If the remainder is 3 or 9, move 2
>    to the end of the list.
> 4. Append the
>    odd numbers from 1 to n in order,
>    but, if the remainder is 8, switch
>    pairs (i.e. 3, 1, 7, 5, 11, 9, …).
> 5. If the remainder is 2, switch the
>    places of 1 and 3, then move 5 to
>    the end of the list.
> 6. If the
>    remainder is 3 or 9, move 1 and 3 to
>    the end of the list.
> 7. Place the
>    first-column queen in the row with
>    the first number in the list, place
>    the second-column queen in the row
>    with the second number in the list,
>    etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple C# Solution
I think it works

```
public static class EightQueens
    {
        static   int[] board = new int[8];
        static int MaxRows = 8, MaxCols = 8;
        public static int[] GetPosition()
        {
            if (GetPosition(0)) return board;
            else return null;
        }
        public static bool IsCollision(int row, int col)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
            {
                if (board[i] == row) return true; // Same Row
                if ((board[i] + col - i == row) || (board[i] - col + i == row))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
        public static bool GetPosition(int col)
        {
            if (col == MaxCols) return true;
            for (int row = 0; row < MaxRows; row++)
                if (!IsCollision(row, col))
                {
                    board[col] = row;
                    if (GetPosition(col + 1)) return true;
                }
            return false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In [EWD316](http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd03xx/EWD316.PDF), Dijkstra derives a solution to the Eight Queens problem rather formally. Try it, you might like it!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NQueensSolver
{
    private readonly List<int[]> _solutions = new List<int[]>();
    private readonly int[] _current;
    public int N { get; private set; }

    public NQueensSolver(int n)
    {
        N = n;
        _current = new int[N];
    }

    public IList<int[]> FindAllFormations()
    {
        PopulateFormations(0);
        return _solutions;
    }

    private void PopulateFormations(int row)
    {
        if (row == N)
        {
            _solutions.Add(_current.ToArray());
            return;
        }

        for (int col = 0; col <= N-1; col++)
        {
            if (Threatened(row, col))
                continue;

            _current[row] = col;
            PopulateFormations(row + 1);
        }
    }

    private bool Threatened(int row, int col)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= row - 1; i++)
            if (_current[i] == col || row - i == Math.Abs(col - _current[i]))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Some tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestNQueens()
{
  Assert.AreEqual(1, new NQueensSolver(1).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(0, new NQueensSolver(2).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(0, new NQueensSolver(3).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(2, new NQueensSolver(4).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(10, new NQueensSolver(5).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(4, new NQueensSolver(6).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(40, new NQueensSolver(7).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(92, new NQueensSolver(8).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(352, new NQueensSolver(9).FindAllFormations().Count);
  Assert.AreEqual(724, new NQueensSolver(10).FindAllFormations().Count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution in C#.

```
//----N Queens ----
public static bool NQueens(bool[,] board, int x)
{
      for (int y = 0; y < board.GetLength(1); y++)
      {
          if (IsAllowed(board, x, y))
          {
               board[x, y] = true;
               if (x == board.GetLength(0) - 1 || NQueens(board, x + 1))
               {
                   return true;
               }
               board[x, y] = false;
          }
     }
     return false;
}
//verify diagonals, column and row from i=0 to x because from x to down it dont put anything
private static bool IsAllowed(bool[,] board, int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (board[i, y] || (i <= y && board[x - i, y - i]) || (y + i < board.GetLength(0) && board[x - i, y + i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [TheWalnut.io](https://thewalnut.io/visualizer/visualize/3595/267/) there's a visualization of the N-Queens: it is considered a constraint satisfaction problem and uses a local-search algorithm (with a min-conflicts heuristic) to solve it. [The code (in Javascript) is also there](https://thewalnut.io/simulations/edit_agent/94/).

The visualization is for particular case of N == 8 but it can be changed to any N.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private const int Size = 8;
    private static readonly bool[,] chessboard = new bool[Size, Size];

    //The Rows are 8, numbered from 0 to 7.
    //The Columns are 8, numbered from 0 to 7.
    //The left diagonals are 15, numbered from -7 to 7. following formula : leftDiag = col - row.
    //The right diagonals are 15, numbered from 0 to 14 by the formula: rightDiag = col + row.
    private static readonly HashSet<int> AttackedRows = new HashSet<int>();

    private static readonly HashSet<int> AttackedCols = new HashSet<int>();

    private static readonly HashSet<int> AttackedLeftDiagonals = new HashSet<int>();

    private static readonly HashSet<int> AttackedRightDiagonals = new HashSet<int>();

    private static int solutionsFound;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PutQueens(0);
        Console.WriteLine(solutionsFound);
    }

    private static void PutQueens(int row)
    {
        if (row == Size)
        {
            PrintBoard();
            solutionsFound++;
        }

        else
        {
            for (var col = 0; col < Size; col++)
            {
                if (CanPlaceQueen(row, col))
                {
                    MarkAllAttackedPositons(row, col);
                    PutQueens(row + 1);
                    UnMarkAllAttackedPositons(row, col);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void UnMarkAllAttackedPositons(int row, int col)
    {
        AttackedRows.Remove(row);
        AttackedCols.Remove(col);
        AttackedLeftDiagonals.Remove(col - row);
        AttackedRightDiagonals.Remove(col + row);
        chessboard[row, col] = false;
    }

    private static void MarkAllAttackedPositons(int row, int col)
    {
        AttackedRows.Add(row);
        AttackedCols.Add(col);
        AttackedLeftDiagonals.Add(col - row);
        AttackedRightDiagonals.Add(col + row);
        chessboard[row, col] = true;
    }

    private static bool CanPlaceQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        var positionOccuppied = AttackedCols.Contains(col) || AttackedRows.Contains(row)
                                || AttackedLeftDiagonals.Contains(col - row)
                                || AttackedRightDiagonals.Contains(col + row);
        return !positionOccuppied;
    }

    private static void PrintBoard()
    {
        for (var row = 0; row < Size; row++)
        {
            for (var col = 0; col < Size; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(chessboard[row, col] ? "Q " : "- ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a [detailed, commented example of the N Queens problem in Python](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/nqueens/blob/master/nqueens.py), and put it up on GitHub. Take a look!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this deploying C++, see the right moves on terminal.

[image]

You might see more details on [my queen.cpp](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/DataStructures/blob/master/queen.cpp)

function for placing chess

```
void amo::Queen::place(int probing, int n) {
    if (n != row || n != col ) {
        if (chess != nullptr) {
            for (int i=0;i<row;i++) delete *(chess+i);
            delete chess;
        }   
        row = n;
        col = n;
        chess = new int*[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            *(chess+i) = new int[col];
            for (int j=0; j<col; j++) 
                *(*(chess+i)+j) = 100*(i+1)+j;
        }
    }
    if (probing >= n) {
        ans += 1;
        std::cout << GREEN <<"[Queen::place()]: returns when met the pass-the-end of probing which means deduced one of answer:" << ans << WHITE << std::endl;
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=queens.begin(); it!=std::next(queens.begin(), n); it++)
            collect(moves, 1, std::distance(queens.begin(), it), *it);
        traverse(moves);
        moves.clear();
        return;
    }
    for (int pruning=0; pruning<col; pruning++) {
        track++;
        //traverse(probing, pruning);
        //if (probing==n-1 && pruning==col-1) std::cout << RED <<"[Queen::place()]: track:" << track << WHITE << std::endl; //final track=4^4+4^3+4^2+4^1=340 if n=4 or track=3^3+3^2+3^1=39 if n=3
        if (!check(probing, pruning)) {
        //if (false) { //watching all moves
            //std::cout << "[Queen::place()]: going to prune" << WHITE << std::endl;
            /**
             * 'prunes' when met one of dead ends of this probing at this pruning
             */
            continue;
        }
        else { //found one of rights of this probing at this pruning and digs into the one more deeper 
            //std::cout << "[Queen::place()]: going to probe" << WHITE << std::endl;
            if (queens.size() < n) queens.resize(n);
            queens.at(probing) = pruning;
            /**
             * 'probes' one more deeper by making one more call stack returning back here as backtracking and proceeding to another pruning
             */ 
            place(probing+1, n);
        }
    }
    /**
     * 'backtracks'
     */ 
    return;
}
```

and function for checking if moves are solutions

```
bool amo::Queen::check(int row, int column) {
    if (row == 0) {
        //std::cout << CYAN << "okay chess[" << row <<"][" << column << "]" << WHITE << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=queens.begin(); it!=std::next(queens.begin(), row); it++) {
        int placed_row = std::distance(queens.begin(), it);
        int placed_column = queens.at(placed_row);
        if (placed_column == column) {
            //std::cout << MAGENTA << "not across,   queen[" << placed_row << "][" << placed_column << "] and chess[" << row <<"][" << column << "]" << WHITE << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (std::abs(placed_column-column) == std::abs(placed_row-row)) {
            //std::cout << MAGENTA << "not diagonal, queen[" << placed_row << "][" << placed_column << "] and chess[" << row <<"][" << column << "]" << WHITE << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    //std::cout << CYAN << "okay chess[" << row <<"][" << column << "]" << WHITE << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
with tx1 as (select 1 as k union all select t2.k + 1 from tx1 as t2 where t2.k < 8)

select *
from tx1 as x1
join tx1 as x2 on 
    x2.k <> x1.k and 
    x2.k <> x1.k + 1 and x2.k <> x1.k - 1
join tx1 as x3 on 
    x3.k <> x1.k and x3.k <> x2.k and 
    x3.k <> x2.k + 1 and x3.k <> x2.k - 1 and
    x3.k <> x1.k + 2 and x3.k <> x1.k - 2
join tx1 as x4 on 
    x4.k <> x1.k and x4.k <> x2.k and x4.k <> x3.k and
    x4.k <> x3.k + 1 and x4.k <> x3.k - 1 and
    x4.k <> x2.k + 2 and x4.k <> x2.k - 2 and
    x4.k <> x1.k + 3 and x4.k <> x1.k - 3
join tx1 as x5 on 
    x5.k <> x1.k and x5.k <> x2.k and x5.k <> x3.k and x5.k <> x4.k and
    x5.k <> x4.k + 1 and x5.k <> x4.k - 1 and
    x5.k <> x3.k + 2 and x5.k <> x3.k - 2 and
    x5.k <> x2.k + 3 and x5.k <> x2.k - 3 and 
    x5.k <> x1.k + 4 and x5.k <> x1.k - 4
join tx1 as x6 on 
    x6.k <> x1.k and x6.k <> x2.k and x6.k <> x3.k and x6.k <> x4.k and x6.k <> x5.k     and
    x6.k <> x5.k + 1 and x6.k <> x5.k - 1 and
    x6.k <> x4.k + 2 and x6.k <> x4.k - 2 and
    x6.k <> x3.k + 3 and x6.k <> x3.k - 3 and 
    x6.k <> x2.k + 4 and x6.k <> x2.k - 4 and 
    x6.k <> x1.k + 5 and x6.k <> x1.k - 5
join tx1 as x7 on 
    x7.k <> x1.k and x7.k <> x2.k and x7.k <> x3.k and x7.k <> x4.k and x7.k <> x5.k and x7.k <> x6.k and
    x7.k <> x6.k + 1 and x7.k <> x6.k - 1 and
    x7.k <> x5.k + 2 and x7.k <> x5.k - 2 and
    x7.k <> x4.k + 3 and x7.k <> x4.k - 3 and 
    x7.k <> x3.k + 4 and x7.k <> x3.k - 4 and 
    x7.k <> x2.k + 5 and x7.k <> x2.k - 5 and
    x7.k <> x1.k + 6 and x7.k <> x1.k - 6
join tx1 as x8 on 
    x8.k <> x1.k and x8.k <> x2.k and x8.k <> x3.k and x8.k <> x4.k and x8.k <> x5.k and x8.k <> x6.k and x8.k <> x7.k and
    x8.k <> x7.k + 1 and x8.k <> x7.k - 1 and
    x8.k <> x6.k + 2 and x8.k <> x6.k - 2 and
    x8.k <> x5.k + 3 and x8.k <> x5.k - 3 and 
    x8.k <> x4.k + 4 and x8.k <> x4.k - 4 and 
    x8.k <> x3.k + 5 and x8.k <> x3.k - 5 and
    x8.k <> x2.k + 6 and x8.k <> x2.k - 6 and
    x8.k <> x1.k + 7 and x8.k <> x1.k - 7
order by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution
https://jsfiddle.net/coder039/2Ljxtus3/3/

```
const log = (...args) => {
  // console.log(...args)
  document.write(...args)
  document.write('<br />')
}

// get the print function (for printing the board)
const getPrint = (n) => (arr) => {
  const print = () => {
    let str = ''
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        str += !!arr.find((o) => o.row === i && o.col === j) ? ' x' : ' o'
      }
      str += `<br />`
    }
    log(str)
  }

  print()
}

const head = (arr) => {
  return arr[0]
}

const tail = (arr) => {
  const [, ...a] = arr
  return a
}

const makePoint = ({
  row,
  col
}) => {
  return {
    row,
    col
  }
}

// check if 2 points attacking each other
const checkTwoPoint = (p1, p2) => {
  const {
    row: row1,
    col: col1
  } = p1
  const {
    row: row2,
    col: col2
  } = p2

  // check not attacking by same row or same col
  if (row1 === row2 || col1 === col2) {
    return false
  }

  // check not attacking by same diagonal line
  if (Math.abs(row1 - row2) === Math.abs(col1 - col2)) {
    return false
  }

  return true
}

// check if one point attacking any point in a list of points (assume list of points includes all points that not attacking each others)
const checkOnePointAndListPoint = (point, ls) => {
  if (ls.length === 0) {
    return true
  }

  return (
    checkTwoPoint(point, head(ls)) && checkOnePointAndListPoint(point, tail(ls))
  )
}
// check if a list of point is valid (no point attacking each others)
// const checkListPoint = (ls) => {
//   if (ls.length <= 1) {
//     return true
//   }
//   if (ls.length === 2) {
//     return checkTwoPoint(ls[0], ls[1])
//   }

//   return checkOnePointAndListPoint(car(ls), cdr(ls)) && checkListPoint(cdr(ls))
// }

const stackMaker = (printFn) => {
  const data = []
  return {
    push: (item) => {
      data.unshift(item)
      printFn(data)
    },
    remove: () => {
      const itemToRemove = data.shift()
      return itemToRemove
    },
    top: () => {
      return data[0]
    },
    listExceptTop: () => {
      return tail(data)
    },
    size: () => {
      return data.length
    },
  }
}

const queen = (n) => {
  const stack = stackMaker(getPrint(n))

  const back = () => {
    const isLastPointAtTheLastRow = () => {
      const lastPoint = stack.top()
      return lastPoint.row === n
    }

    if (!isLastPointAtTheLastRow()) {
      const lastPoint = stack.remove()
      place({
        row: lastPoint.row + 1,
        col: lastPoint.col
      })
    } else {
      stack.remove()
      back()
    }
  }

  const checkValidBoard = () => {
    const lastPoint = stack.top()
    const remainder = stack.listExceptTop()
    const isValid = checkOnePointAndListPoint(lastPoint, remainder)

    if (isValid) {
      place({
        row: 1,
        col: lastPoint.col + 1
      })
    } else {
      back()
    }
  }

  const place = ({
    row,
    col
  }) => {
    if (stack.size() === n) {
      log('done ')
      return 'done'
    }
    const point = makePoint({
      col,
      row
    })
    stack.push(point)
    checkValidBoard()
  }

  place({
    row: 1,
    col: 1
  })
}

queen(4)
```